# Change in last Textbox will update all textboxes with the same value

Tags: validation, c#-4.0, textbox, wpf-4.0

I have added some Validation to my WPF Form, using Gerald Gomes CodeProject Article http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/690130/Simple-Validation-in-WPF
And using this I get a strange problem!

I have this xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestValidate.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestValidate"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationErrorTemplate">
            <DockPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                    <Grid Width="12" Height="12">
                        <Ellipse Width="12" Height="12" Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"

                             ></Ellipse>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontWeight="Heavy" FontSize="8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"
                               ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
                               >X</TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontWeight="12" Margin="2,0,0,0"
                           Text="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
                           ></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="ErrorAdorner" />
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.519,0.497">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,80,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Number" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" />
        <TextBox x:Name="MaxMessageListCount" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="120,73,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Width="156" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorTemplate}" TabIndex="4" ToolTip="Max number of messages that the list will contain before it clears">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="Name" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:NumberValidator />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,126,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Text" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" />
        <TextBox x:Name="ClientId" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="120,119,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Width="156"  Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorTemplate}" TabIndex="5" ToolTip="Client Id MUST be unique for the cell">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="Name" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:EmptyValidator />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And these Validation Rules

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestValidate
{
    public class EmptyValidator : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return new ValidationResult(false, "value can't be empty");
            else
            {
                string sValue = value.ToString();

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sValue))
                    return new ValidationResult(false, "Value can't be empty");
            }
            return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        }
    }

    public class NumberValidator : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return new ValidationResult(false, "value can't be empty");
            else
            {
                if (!IsNumeric(value))
                    return new ValidationResult(false, "value must be a number");
            }
            return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        }

        private bool IsNumeric(object value)
        {
            bool result = true;
            string number = value.ToString();
            int num = -1;
            result = int.TryParse(number, out num);

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the value of the last textbox (x:Name="ClientId") the the entered value will also be filled in int the first textbos (x:Name="MaxMessageListCount")

What have I done wrong?

The whole project can be downloaded from here
http://andis59.se/wpf/TestValidate.zip

// Anders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're binding both of the TextBox's to the 'Name' Property,

```
<Binding Path="Name" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
```

For example, in your case I would bind the ClientId TextBox to

```
<Binding Path="ClientId" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
```

Comment: I actually figured that out myself after a while. The strange this is that in my real program I have about 10 textboxes with all the same binding, but it's only when I add validation to the last textbox I get this error. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I don't realize why would you bind all of the TextBoxes to the same property, if you're actually doing this, then changing any of the boxes would essentially update all the others.

Comment: Well, that because I didn't understand the code, just copied parts of it from the article.